# Pegar informação de um Site e Colocar numa Label?

Tags: c#, navegador-de-internet, label

Eu quero navegar até o Site e Pegar o Valor Atual de Bitcoins pra Inserir numa Label. Essa foi a minha tentativa que claramente não funcionou...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.mercadobitcoin.com.br/");

            HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
            label2.Text = doc.GetElementById("ticker_ultimo_grande-int").OuterText;

        }
```

Área do Site

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<div class="mb-yellow-text text-center relative"><div id="hugePriceBrlSymbol">R$</div>
<div id="ticker_ultimo_grande-int">3924,</div>
<div id="ticker_decimal_group" class="clearfix">
<div id="ticker_ultimo_grande-dec">61</div></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div></div>
```

Mensagem de Erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: no evento `Load` a página ainda não vai ter terminado de ser carregada, muito provavelmente você conseguirá pegar o valor utilizando o evento `private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)`

Comment: o doc tem valor?

Comment: Obrigado! Deu certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro ocorre porque você está tentando pegar 'Document' antes da página estar carregada.

Para corrigir só pegue elementos na página só depois dela estar carregada.

Para saber se a página foi completamente carregada use o evento [`WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted?view=netframework-4.8) que ocorre quando o controle `WebBrowser` termina de carregar um documento.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.mercadobitcoin.com.br/");

 }

 private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
     HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document; 

     label2.Text = doc.GetElementById("ticker_ultimo_grande-int").OuterText;
 }
```

Imagem do seu código funcionando:
[image: Imagem da integração WebBrowser Winform]

Answer (score 0):

O que está acontecendo é que você não está dando tempo do site carregar para o programa.
 Acredito que se você colocar um `Thread.Sleep(3)` antes, funcione.

Answer (score 0):

Sérgio Wilker, se você está falando de "WebCrawler" ou "WebScraping" eu fiz assim para retornar o Dólar Comercial de um site chamado "The Money Converter":

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;

/// <summary>
/// Faz a busca do Dólar Comercial no site da The Money Converter
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Retorna Dólar Comercial</returns>
public static string RetornaDolarComercialTheMoneyConverter()
{
    string url = @"https://themoneyconverter.com/USD/BRL.aspx";
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
    HtmlNode value = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='cc-ratebox']");

    string strValue = value.InnerText;
    // Precisei formatar com vírgula.
    strValue = strValue.Replace('.', ',');
    strValue = "R$ " + strValue.Substring(strValue.IndexOf("=", 0) + 2, 7);

    return strValue;
}
```

É preciso usar o navegador, google por exemplo, na parte de "Mais Ferramentas" / "Ferramentas do Desenvolvedor" e ir procurando o que você quer extrair (dentro de uma DIV, por exemplo), e usando o botão do lado direito do mouse fazer um "Copy / Copy XPath", pegar o termo exato que será extraido do site (o conteúdo). Exemplo:

```
// *[@id="cc-ratebox"]
```

Espero que seja isso que você procura. Se quiser, posso passar um programa completo...

[]'s,

Fabio I.